# Phonegap (Cordova) doesn't write file to Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm having a frustrating issue getting cordova to write files to Android devices.

According to the log, everything is firing correctly and the plugin methods are responding with successes etc, but when I go searching for the files they're no where to be found.

Currently I'm just using a fresh phonegap test application and I followed the following guide and used their example code verbatim. The plugins are installed according to the logs are executing.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html

I'm expecting the file to show up in /android/data/com.testapp.myapp/files

This is my test code:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, app.gotFS, app.fail);
    },

    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    },

    gotFS: function(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("testFile.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, app.gotFileEntry, app.fail);
    },

    gotFileEntry: function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(app.gotFileWriter, app.fail);
    },

    gotFileWriter: function(writer) {
        writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
            console.log("contents of file now 'some sample text'");
            writer.truncate(11);
            writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
                console.log("contents of file now 'some sample'");
                writer.seek(4);
                writer.write(" different text");
                writer.onwriteend = function(evt){
                    console.log("contents of file now 'some different text'");
                }
            };
        };
        writer.write("some sample text");

    },

    fail: function() {
        alert("failed");
    }    
};
```

And here are the log entries from the logCat showing it firing off:

```
09-26 07:24:37.991 I/chromium( 2027): [INFO:CONSOLE(49)] "Received   

Event: deviceready", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js (49)
09-26 07:24:38.591 D/TEST    ( 2027): cdvfile://localhost/persistent/testFile.txt: 16
09-26 07:24:39.063 I/chromium( 2027): [INFO:CONSOLE(62)] "contents of file now 'some sample text'", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js (62)
09-26 07:24:39.075 D/TEST    ( 2027): cdvfile://localhost/persistent/testFile.txt: 15
09-26 07:24:39.155 I/chromium( 2027): [INFO:CONSOLE(65)] "contents of file now 'some sample'", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js (65)
09-26 07:24:39.363 I/chromium( 2027): [INFO:CONSOLE(69)] "contents of file now 'some different text'", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js (69)
```

Any insight to why this maybe happening would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make it so complex dude , it's a code snipest to write data to file . data which stored in 'decdata' variable . Don't forget to change 'somefolder' for folder in root directory and  'datafilename' the file which data is stored. 
Also you should add file plugin .

```
function start(){
       window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, writedata, fail);
}
    var decdata;

 function writedata(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory("<<somefolder>>", { create: true }, gotDir);
    }


 function gotDir(dirEntry) {

        dirEntry.getFile(<<datafilename>>, { create: true, exclusive: false }, gotFile);
    }


function gotFile(fileEntry) {

        fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);

    }

    function gotFileWriter(writer) {
        writer.onwriteend = function (evt) {
            writer.truncate(1);
            writer.onwriteend = function (evt) {
                writer.seek(0);
                writer.write(decdata);
                writer.onwriteend = function (evt) {

                }
            };
        };
        writer.write("some sample text");
    }
    function fail(error) {
        alert('error' + error.code);
    }
```

Comment: I suspect that it is working properly and that the file is being written to a root level directory that is unreachable via the devices file manager. The log indication that everything is working (the plugin's responding as successful method executions)


Is there a way to make sure the application writes to the app's folder in /android/data/com.phonegap.testapp/data/files